# I have duplicated a table and the number of rows don't match

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have tried to find this information but wasn't able. I had a table with somewhere around 5500 and 6500 rows. I checked this number by going into the 'i' for information symbol on MySQL Workbench, but there's an update button, which when pressed will change the row count. Is that normal? Is this number of rows too big for mysql? (there's around 12 columns, if this is necessary info)

OK. After that, I duplicated this table using:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE table1; 
INSERT table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

After that, when checking 'i' information for number of rows from both tables, which were supposed to be equal, the numbers don' match. Even if I update both, they still don't match. What is going on? Should I worry? Thanks a lot

Comment: You are using `count(*)` or system metadata?  The latter might be approximate.

Comment: " I checked this number by going into the 'i' for information symbol on MySQL Workbench, but there's an update button, which when pressed will change the row count." Sounds like your database is inconsistant with itself, maybe you should manually select the rows of table1 and table2 and compare, secondly it sounds like your table1 is getting updated but table2 is not??

Comment: The row count in the Info Panel is only a guess. If  you really want to know the correct row number you have to do a query select count(*) from table

Comment: Use `CREATE TABLE table2 SELECT * FROM table1;` that saves one  query.